# Who was the serial killer in Dean Koontz's Demon Seed

Tags: character-identification, dean-koontz

I read Demon Seed a while back and remember that it featured a serial killer the protagonist frees from prison by hacking a chip in his brain. I no longer have the book though.

I've searched online but I can't find a reference to the character.

The problem seems to be,  that Dean Koontz has a predeliction for putting serial killers in his stories and all I'm bringing up are Enoch Cain from 'From the corner of his eye' and the killer in Watchers. The killer in Demon Seed plays a much smaller role.

What was his name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “I have an associate,” I said.
>
> “Associate?”
>
> “A gentleman who assists me.”
>
> In the farthest corner of the room, the closet door opened and, at my command, Shenk appeared.
>
> “Oh, Jesus,” she whispered. Shenk walked toward her

It's Enos Shenk.

Sheck isn't a serial killer though. He was fitted with the chips in his brain as part of a government project to try and develop the perfect assassin. However he is an extremely nasty piece of work.

Comment: I can see how I mixed up *Enoch* and *Enos*....